# Django googlebot crawling ajax url

Tags: ajax, django, url, googlebot

I have setup a Django site and receiving this alert from GoogleBot that I think it put in a test paramater (zero) at my URL. Zero is nonexistant primary key in my database

```
<WSGIRequest
path:/for_sale_detail/0/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate',
'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
'HTTP_FROM': 'googlebot(at)googlebot.com',
'HTTP_HOST': 'example.com',
'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
```

This is my url.py with the first group of digits is my primary key (example below is number 2):

```
url(r'^for_sale_detail/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', for_sale_detail, name='for_sale_detail'),
```

and in my html file, ajax URL (dynamic content populated after user interaction) is called in such way:

```
var slug = '2-terrace-link-house';

for (abc < 10)
{
    ...
    slug = new_url;
    call_detail_page(); 
}

function call_detail_page()
{
    var detail_page_url = "{% url 'for_sale_detail' '2-terrace-link-house' %}".replace ('2-terrace-link-house', slug);

     $.colorbox({
        iframe : true,      
        width : '1200px',
        height : '600px',           
        href:detail_page_url
        });     
}
```

I've created sitemap.xml file to point to all valid slug address but still when GoogleBot crawls, it will append "0" to my URL slug. Ideally, I would want all detail pages to be indexed and found by google thus will not want to redirect GoogleBot to a nonexistant page

a valid URL is this:

```
http://www.example.com/for_sale_detail/2-terrace-link-house
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check on for_sale_detail if the item exists and return [HttpResponseNotFound](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotFound) or raise [Http404 exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception) if not.

Comment: Thats what I don't want to do initially as I want GoogleBot to crawl through this page using sitemap but maybe can implement this as don't think GoogleBot can generate any random url slug